# I'm getting a error on an AVL tree search problem

Tags: python, search, avl-tree

I'm trying to do a search function for an AVL-tree, when i try to search for a number that is in the tree the code works fine, but i'm getting the error

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'search'

when a try to search for a number that isn't in the tree

This is the search function

```
    def search(self, data):
   
      if self is None:
        return "the key doesn't exist"  
      elif data < self.data:
        return self.left.busca(data)
      elif data > self.data:
        return self.right.busca(data)
      else:
        return "the key exist"
```

and the whole code(the name of the variables are in pt-br)

```
class No:
def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self.setaFilhos(None, None)

def setaFilhos(self, esquerda, direita):
    self.esquerda = esquerda
    self.direita = direita

def balanco(self):
    prof_esq = 0
    if self.esquerda:
        prof_esq = self.esquerda.profundidade()
    prof_dir = 0
    if self.direita:
        prof_dir = self.direita.profundidade()
    return prof_esq - prof_dir

def profundidade(self):
    prof_esq = 0
    if self.esquerda:
        prof_esq = self.esquerda.profundidade()
    prof_dir = 0
    if self.direita:
        prof_dir = self.direita.profundidade()
    return 1 + max(prof_esq, prof_dir)

def rotacaoEsquerda(self):
    self.data, self.direita.data = self.direita.data, self.data
    old_esquerda = self.esquerda
    self.setaFilhos(self.direita, self.direita.direita)
    self.esquerda.setaFilhos(old_esquerda, self.esquerda.esquerda)

def rotacaoDireita(self):
    self.data, self.esquerda.data = self.esquerda.data, self.data
    old_direita = self.direita
    self.setaFilhos(self.esquerda.esquerda, self.esquerda)
    self.direita.setaFilhos(self.direita.direita, old_direita)

def rotacaoEsquerdaDireita(self):
    self.esquerda.rotacaoEsquerda()
    self.rotacaoDireita()

def rotacaoDireitaEsquerda(self):
    self.direita.rotacaoDireita()
    self.rotacaoEsquerda()

def executaBalanco(self):
    bal = self.balanco()
    if bal > 1:
        if self.esquerda.balanco() > 0:
            self.rotacaoDireita()
        else:
            self.rotacaoEsquerdaDireita()
    elif bal < -1:
        if self.direita.balanco() < 0:
            self.rotacaoEsquerda()
        else:
            self.rotacaoDireitaEsquerda()

def insere(self, data):
    if data <= self.data:
        if not self.esquerda:
            self.esquerda = No(data)
        else:
            self.esquerda.insere(data)
    else:
        if not self.direita:
            self.direita = No(data)
        else:
            self.direita.insere(data)
    self.executaBalanco()

def remove(self, data):
    if self.direita is None and self.esquerda is None:
        return None
    if data < self.data:
        self.esquerda = self.esquerda.remove(data)
    elif data > self.data:
        self.direita = self.direita.remove(data)
    else:
        if self.direita is None:
            return self.esquerda
        if self.esquerda is None:
            return self.direita
        tmp = self.direita._min()
        self.data = tmp.data 
        self.direita = self.direita.remove(tmp.data)
    self.executaBalanco()
    return self
  
def busca(self, data):
  if self is None:
        return "A chave não existe"  
  elif data < self.data:
    return self.esquerda.busca(data)
  elif data > self.data:
    return self.direita.busca(data)
  else:
    return "A chave existe"
     
def _min(self):
    if self.esquerda is None:
        return self
    else:
        return self.esquerda._min()

def imprimeArvore(self, indent = 0):
    print ( "-" * indent + "|" + str(self.data))
    if self.esquerda:
        self.esquerda.imprimeArvore(indent + 2)
    if self.direita:
        self.direita.imprimeArvore(indent + 2)
arvore = None
for data in [15, 27, 49, 10, 8, 67, 59, 9, 13, 20, 14]:
if arvore:
   arvore.insere(data)
else:
  arvore = No(data)
arvore.imprimeArvore()
arvore.busca(1)
```

I think the problem is the returning when the key is not found, but i not sure, none of the similar question that i tried to read helped me and i tried to look the code of other people and at least for me my code should work . What did i do wrong?There is another way to do it?

Comment: Where is the search method being called in your whole code?

Comment: the last line of the whole code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    def search(self, data):
   
      if self is None:
        return "the key doesn't exist"  
      elif data < self.data:
        return self.left.busca(data)
      elif data > self.data:
        return self.right.busca(data)
      else:
        return "the key exist"
```

If the search method is called successfully, `self` is not None.
You should check whether `self.left` is None or `self.right` is None before making the recursive call to `search`.

```
    def search(self, data):
   
      if data == self.data:
        return "the key exists"
       
      if data < self.data and self.left is not None:
        return self.left.busca(data)
      elif data > self.data and self.right is not None:
        return self.right.busca(data)
      else:
        return "the key exist"
```